# updating all values in a structure at once with single memory write operation in C?

Tags: c, structure

Whats the use with one-line method and updating each variable separately? Does this optimize 3 memory write operations to one?

Or is there any other  way to write all values in a structure with single memory write operation?

```
theTest[0] = (test_t){7,8,9};
   (and)
theTest[0].var1 = 7
theTest[0].var2 = 8
theTest[0].var3 = 9


typedef struct
{
  int var1;
  int var2;
  int var3;
} test_t;
test_t theTest[2];
```

Comment: This suffix `_t` is a good practice for `typedef`s!

Comment: @WedaPashi, no not at all. On POSIX platforms that suffix is reserved for the platform, user code should never use this.

Answer (score 1):

With the given `struct` definition, the semantics of the two options are the same - from the point of view of C, there's no difference.  If the structure had contained more fields, then the first option would zero those fields whereas the second would not.

In pratice, whether or not one memory write can be used depends on the size of the maximum memory write offered by the architecture that you're compiling for.  With large structures, the first option might result in the compiler use a (possibly inlined) call to `memcpy()`.

There's not really any strong reason to prefer one over the other - use whichever you think is neatest.

Comment: thanks for your response..so, does that mean: even if we dont use memcpy to write/update all variables in a structure, like        'theTest[0].var1 = 7;
theTest[0].var2 = 8;
theTest[0].var3 = 9 ;theTest[0].var3 = 9;'   does compiler takes this into one memory write writing all four vars at once (or) write each one variable at a time?

Comment: @user2218872: Yes, the compiler can fold multiple assignments into one memory write if it would be an advantage to do so.